# Format a field so it auto populates as a value without dashes from a value with dashes, Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, select

I have two fields, SSN and ID#. The SSN is entered with dashes and the ID# field is the SSN number without dashes, used in other places of the database. These fields have been manually entered. I would like to automate the process so after a value has been entered in the SSN field (with dashes) it will automatically display in the ID# field without dashes. I can get this to work sort of but it is still slightly manual. If create a lookup for ID

```
SELECT [Table1].[ID#], [Table1].[SSN] FROM Table1;
```

this displays all of my entered SSNs without dashes in the drop down but I still have to select them from the drop down. To get the dropdown to update with new SSNs I have to refresh before I can select the newly added value in the ID dropdown. I was able to do this by creating the lookup for ID then I set the input mask for SSN. This is still a manual process and allows for error.

I am sure this is very easy but I am unable to find it. I would like the simplest approach possible. Any help/example is greatly appreciated. Please assume, I know next to nothing about Access. Thank you.

Comment: Basically saving the same data in 2 fields. Why don't you set the InputMask to save the SSN without dashes? Otherwise, use VBA to set value in the second field using Replace() function to remove the dashes.

Comment: @June7 I have historical data that must be maintained so I cannot save the ID field without dashes. Can you please provide Replace() function or link to good documentation?

Comment: It's a very simple function. `Replace([fieldname], "-", "")`. Google it for more guidance.

Comment: @June7 that does auto-populate just replaces, I need a function to do both as outlined in the original question. It only solves part of the question.

Comment: Use that expression in VBA procedure (probably the SSN AfterUpdate event) to set the value of field. However, that is not really necessary. Can just use the expression in query or textbox to display SSN without dashes whenever needed.

Comment: If you need to update the field for existing records, run an UPDATE sql action using the expression: `UPDATE tablename SET [ID#]=Replace([SSN],"-","")` Advise not to use punctuation or special characters (underscore only exception) in names. Better would be IDNum or ID_Num.

Comment: thanks @June7. I was not putting the function in the correct event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[June7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7607190/june7)
It's a very simple function. Replace([fieldname], "-", ""). Google it for more guidance. – June7 yesterday

Use that expression in VBA procedure (probably the SSN AfterUpdate event) to set the value of field. However, that is not really necessary. Can just use the expression in query or textbox to display SSN without dashes whenever needed. –